# Could not upgrade the latest node version using Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

I need to upgrade the node.js version in my ubuntu machine but after doing it also its also showing the old version. I am explaining my command below.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Previously my version was `v6.9.1` . I run the above command in terminal to upgrade the latest version but after successfully installing its still showing `v6.9.1` when I am doing `node -v` in my terminal. Here I need to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: `apt-get update` before `apt-get install -y nodejs` ?

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar : I did as per you but still its showing that previous version.